# Divide list into chunks of equal size without losing the elements left at the last?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

If I have a list as:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Is there a function or package that lets you specify the length of the combinations you're interested in without losing the remaining elements of the list?

For example, if I was interested in all combinations of length 4, could I return something like:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10]]
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9],[10]]
```

I have been using `itertools.combination` to get the first list, which is great, but I'm looking for a way to keep the remaining list information into account.

NOTE: I'm not looking for anyone to write code for me to solve it if that's what's required. I'm just asking in case someone knows of a similar function that might help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`get_chunks(iterable_obj, chunk_size)`](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-chunks) function of the third-party open-source library [**`utilspie`**](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to achieve this as:

```
>>> from utilspie import iterutils
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#    v type-cast it to `list` as `get_chunks` returns the generator object
>>> list(iterutils.get_chunks(x, 4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

`utilspie` is available on [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utilspie), and **to install do**:

```
# For Python 2.x
pip install utilspie

# For python 3.x
pip3 install utilspie
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I am the creator of this library: https://github.com/moin18/utilspie

Comment: Not sure why it got a down vote, but very impressive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [more-itertools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) and its `sliced()` function, as well.

```
>>> import more_itertools
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list(more_itertools.sliced(x, 4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```